# My .htaccess redirect is redirecting to wrong urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I recently converted a wordpress webshop to a magento webshop. Now i want all the old urls that are indexed by the search engines redirect to the new ones from magento.
Since it were only about 150 products i thought i'd do it manually.

This is what i tried for all the products :

```
Redirect 301 /products-page/accu/unibat-ctz5s-bs/ http://www.domain.nl/accu-s/unibat-ctz5s-bs.html
```

It does try to redirect, but it ends up at this URL : http://www.domain.nl/accu-s.htmlunibat-ctz5s-bs/ , which gives a 404 :(

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: is this the only line of code in your _.htaccess_ file..?? and is this the only _.htaccess_ file on domain.nl..??

Comment: Hi no, there are many lines in the .htaccess file. Its a standard magento .htaccess file with about 150 extra lines of redirects like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your mod_rewrite rules at the end of your htaccess is interferring with your mod_alias directives (the `Redirect` statements). In this case, you need to do the redirect, then jump out of the URL/file mapping pipeline and since both mod_rewrite and mod_alias get to do their thing in the pipeline, they both mangle the URI. Just stick with mod_rewrite, change all of your statements to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?products-page/accu/unibat-ctz5s-bs/$ http://www.domain.nl/accu-s/unibat-ctz5s-bs.html [L,R=301]
```

These need to go *before* any of your other rules. But also keep in mind, the way the `Redirect` statement works vs redirecting using `RewriteRule`. The `Rewrite` "links" 2 URI-path nodes together. So something like:

```
Redirect 301 /foo http://www.domain.nl/bar
```

Would link `/foo` and `/bar` together, thus a request for `/foo/blah/blah.html` would redirect to `http://www.domain.nl/bar/blah/blah.html`. In order to translate this functionality to a rewrite rule you'd need:

```
RewriteRule ^/?foo(.*)$ http://www.domain.nl/bar$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! When i use the rewrite rule, it works. Just on one product tho. The rest still redirects to the wrong url :(

Comment: @DavidEricsson you have to change all your `Redirect` statements to the equivalent `RewriteRule`. The point is mod_alias and mod_rewrite isn't playing nicely with each other so you can't use mod_alias **at all** in the paths that overlap.

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin! You are my hero!